# Zip Kit Integration with Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.3

I am trying to use zip/unzip functionality in my iOS app for that purpose I found one library from blog link -  https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/UsingZipKit.

I am using Xcode 4.3 and getting below error

```
ZKDefs.h, ZKFileArchive.h No such file or directory
```

I have followed all instructions but still getting this error. Anyone has tried this library for Xcode 4.3 iOS 5? May be I am getting this error due to Header path, but I am unable to solve this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I am using shell command and trying to zip/unzip through it. It worked for me on simulator.

e.g
           system("zip newfile.zip oldfile.rtf");